# How to insert 1 interval numbers between given irregular numbers in python

Tags: python

I've generated index number list what I do find data using for-loop.

That numbers are as follows.

I want to generate 1 interval index numbers between each given numbers

```
Int64Index([ 2343,  2913,  5466,  8589, 10151, 11713, 13275, 14837, 15618,7961, 19523, 21624, 21700],dtype='int64')
```

for e.g) 2343,2344,2345,2346 ......,2911,2912,2913,2914....5464,5465,5466 some thing like that.

Is there any method that i generate 1 interval numbers do not use for-loop?

Comment: Did you try `range()`?

Comment: Just a note, if all your values are in order like this, only the first and last values are relevant, any intermediates are redundant as they will be passed over anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the builtin [**range()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function.

First you need to determine start and end number using the [**min()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [**max()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) functions.

```
start_num = min(listr)
end_num = max(listr)
```

Then we use **range()** to create our new list

```
new_listr = list(range(start_num, end_num+1))
```

The complete sample code:

```
listr = [2343,  2913,  5466,  8589, 10151, 11713, 13275, 14837, 15618,7961, 19523, 21624, 21700]
start_num = min(listr)
end_num = max(listr)
new_listr = list(range(start_num, end_num+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
>>> range(1,10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1,10,1)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1,10,2)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> range(1,10,3)
[1, 4, 7]
>>> help(range)
Help on built-in function range in module __builtin__:

range(...)
    range(stop) -> list of integers
    range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers

    Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
    range(i, j) returns [i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1]; start (!) defaults to 0.
    When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
    For example, range(4) returns [0, 1, 2, 3].  The end point is omitted!
    These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
(END)
```